# Using ng-if inside ng-options to filter null results

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter out "null" results from a select dropdown list.
Until now I was using just regular html `<select>` + `<option>` with `ng-repeat` and excluding null result this way:

```
<option ng-repeat="person in showCase.persons" ng-if="person.profiles">
{{person.profiles}}
</option>
```

This way I could get a list without empty/null 'user profile'.
Now I started using `ng-options` instead because the list includes arrays with objects,
but I can't get the null results out - ..when I'm using `ng-if` the whole `<select>` disappears :

```
<select ng-model="profile_filter" ng-options="person.profiles for person in persons"  
ng-if="person.profiles">
</select>
```

My priority was doing it inline and not in my controller because there's many `<select>` objects in the page, and some do require the "null" results to show.
I know, it's a very basic question, but still it got me stuck for the last 2 hours.
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you just filter it out at the source, in the controller or service rather than trying to fix it on the view. when you use `ng-if` on the select it is on the select looking for a property on the scope which is not there. `person.profiles for person` is a mere expression for ng-options

Comment: Hi PSL, thanks for the input. My priority was doing it inline because there's many `<select>` objects in the page, and some requires the "null" results to show. Kind'a messy :/

Comment: You could just use a filter to filter out null values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `ng-if` on the select it is on the select looking for a property on the scope `person.profiles` which is not there. `person.profiles for person in persons` is a mere expression for `ng-options`.

You could just filter out nulls from the controller itself before binding it. Or create a filter or just use a filter expression with the existing angular core `filter`.

Example:-

In your controller define a function on the scope to remove if profiles is falsy (You can make it explicit as you need), if you return truthy then the item will be added as option else it will be ignored:

```
$scope.removeNull = function(itm) {
    return itm.profiles;
  }
```

And just use it in the view:-

```
<select ng-model="profile_filter"
    ng-options="person.profiles for person in persons|filter:removeNull">
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.persons = [{
    profiles: null
  }, {
    profiles: "prf1"
  }, {
    profiles: "prf2"
  }, {
    profiles: "prf3"
  }, {
    profiles: null
  }, {
    profiles: "prf4"
  }]

  $scope.removeNull = function(itm) {
    return itm.profiles;
  }
  $scope.profile_filter = $scope.persons[1];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="profile_filter" ng-options="person.profiles for person in persons|filter:removeNull">
  </select>
  {{profile_filter}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ng-if="person.profiles!=null"` to get a boolean value.